# Parsing data from big json field and geocode services then store to PostgreSQL using psycopg2 instead django-orm

Tags: python, performance, sql, postgresql, geospatial

This code works, but my boss told me that it's very bad code, and don't want to deploy it. It is my first time working as a programmer and I have at least 3 months of experience.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2.extras
import time
import json
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
from methods_grabber import get_district, get_city,\
                            get_street, get_house, get_postcode
time_start = time.time()

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=gym user=gyms")

def get_data():

    global conn

    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    dict_cur.execute("""
                    SELECT *
                    FROM dblgis_grabber_firm;
                    """
                    )

    res = dict_cur.fetchall()
    dict_cur.close()
    return res

def update_data(id_row, row, data):
    global conn

    cur = conn.cursor()

    query = "UPDATE dblgis_grabber_firm SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s;"

    cur.execute(query, (AsIs(row), data, id_row))

    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    return cur.rowcount

data = get_data()

def get_from_contacts(contact_group, row_name, representation, id_row):
    result = []
    for contacts in contact_group:
        for contact in contacts.get('contacts'):
            if contact.get('type') == representation:
                result.append(unicode(contact.get('text')))
    result = '; '.join(result)
    update_data(id_row, row_name, result)

def fill_data(instance):

    longitude = instance.get('longitude')
    latitude = instance.get('latitude')

    id_row = instance.get('id')

    contact_group = json.loads(instance.get('all_data', {})).get('contact_groups', {})


    if not instance.get('street'):
        street = get_street(longitude, latitude)
        if street:
            update_data(id_row, 'street', street)

    if not instance.get('street_number'):
        street_number = get_house(longitude, latitude)
        if street_number:
            update_data(id_row, 'street_number', street_number)

    if not instance.get('postcode'):
        postcode = get_postcode(longitude, latitude)
        if postcode:
            update_data(id_row, 'postcode', postcode)

    get_from_contacts(contact_group, 'phone_number', 'phone', id_row)
    get_from_contacts(contact_group, 'site', 'website', id_row)
    get_from_contacts(contact_group, 'email', 'email', id_row)


for d in data:
    fill_data(d)

conn.close()

print 'Timeit %s' % (time.time() - time_start)
```

It use my methods from [methods](http://pastebin.com/r91sbs8b), which resolves data from yandex and geopy lib.

After parsing big JSON data, it writes changes to the DB. It's tested for 4k elements and works for 230sec. I think it's normal, but why is it so bad?

Comment: Rewriting code to use Django ORM is outside the scope of Code Review.

Comment: I never ask to rewrite. I ask concrete - do you think it's a bad sample of code, even if it works? I mean, I know it's bad, it should be, but why it's a disaster, I can't get.

Comment: If every geocoding query requires an HTTP request, there probably isn't that much you can do to improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid globals

There is no need in using the `global` keyword here since you’re not modifying your `conn`. But there is also no need to access this variable at global scope, you can easily pass it as parameter.

One of the advantages of using parameters instead of a global variable being that you can more easily test each function with a custom connection when you need to.

## Avoid top-level code

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=gym user=gyms")
data = get_data(conn) # Adding parameter from previous advice
for d in data:
    fill_data(conn, d) # Adding parameter from previous advice
conn.close()
```

Is better within its own function: you get the workflow at first glance. You can also use the function parameters to pass the connection credentials.

Using a function here lets you easily write:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_start = time.time()
    check_data("dbname=gym user=gyms")
    print 'Timeit %s' % (time.time() - time_start)
```

You clearly see there what is computation and what is timming. This is also best practice to wrap the executable part of your code under [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/5069029).

But you are usually better off using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) for performances measurement.

## Avoid managing database state yourself

`psycopg2` provide context managers to wrap connection or cursor objects. For the former it handles auto-commit/rollback based on how things went within the context; and for the latter it auto-closes it.

You can thus write

```
def get_data(conn):
    with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor) as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""
                       SELECT *
                       FROM dblgis_grabber_firm;
                       """)
        return cursor.fetchall()
```

and for `update_data`, you’ll need to auto-commit/rollback the connection:

```
def update_data(conn, id_row, row, data):
    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                "UPDATE dblgis_grabber_firm SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s;",
                (AsIs(row), data, id_row)
            )
```

I removed the `return` statement since you never make use of it.

## Improve `get_from_contacts`

First of, the name is misleading. It doesn't get anything, it set data in the database. It probably should be named `update_from_contacts`. Alternatively, you could keep the name `get_from_contacts` and have that function actually do what it claims to do; and nothing more:

```
def get_from_contacts(contact_group, representation):
    result = []
    for contacts in contact_group:
        for contact in contacts.get('contacts'):
            if contact.get('type') == representation:
                result.append(unicode(contact.get('text')))
    return '; '.join(result)
```

You will need to have `update_data` calls near your `get_from_contact`s; but it separate concerns. And you can save on number of parameters.

You could also improve the overall execution: initialyzing a list to the empty list and appending inside a for loop is often an anti-pattern in python and better served with a list comprehension. Here the `join` call calls to using a generator expression:

```
def get_from_contacts(contact_group, representation):
    return '; '.join(
        unicode(contact.get('text'))
        for contacts in contact_group
        for contact in contacts.get('contacts')
        if contact.get('type') == representation
    )
```

## Avoid redundancy

In `fill_data`, there are several constructions that look alike. You should be able to extract the structure from the data and use iterations to achieve the desired result without copy/pasting similar blocks of code:

```
GEO_FETCH = {
    'street': get_street,
    'street_number': get_house,
    'postcode': get_postcode,
}

CONTACT_FIELDS = {
    'phone_number': 'phone',
    'site': 'website',
    'email': 'email',
}

def fill_data(conn, instance):
    longitude = instance.get('longitude')
    latitude = instance.get('latitude')

    id_row = instance.get('id')

    contact_group = json.loads(
        instance.get('all_data', {})
    ).get('contact_groups', {})

    for field, fetcher in GEO_FETCH.iteritems():
        if not instance.get(field):
            geo_data = fetcher(longitude, latitude)
            if geo_data:
                update_data(conn, id_row, field, geo_data)

    for row_name, field_name in CONTACT_FIELDS.iteritems():
        row_data = get_from_contacts(contact_group, field_name)
        update_data(conn, id_row, row_name, row_data)
```

## Bringing it all together

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import psycopg2.extras
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
from methods_grabber import (get_district, get_city,
                             get_street, get_house, get_postcode)


GEO_FETCH = {
    'street': get_street,
    'street_number': get_house,
    'postcode': get_postcode,
}

CONTACT_FIELDS = {
    'phone_number': 'phone',
    'site': 'website',
    'email': 'email',
}

def fill_data(conn, instance):
    longitude = instance.get('longitude')
    latitude = instance.get('latitude')

    id_row = instance.get('id')

    contact_group = json.loads(
        instance.get('all_data', {})
    ).get('contact_groups', {})

    for field, fetcher in GEO_FETCH.iteritems():
        if not instance.get(field):
            geo_data = fetcher(longitude, latitude)
            if geo_data:
                update_data(conn, id_row, field, geo_data)

    for row_name, field_name in CONTACT_FIELDS.iteritems():
        row_data = get_from_contacts(contact_group, field_name)
        update_data(conn, id_row, row_name, row_data)

def get_from_contacts(contact_group, representation):
    return '; '.join(
        unicode(contact.get('text'))
        for contacts in contact_group
        for contact in contacts.get('contacts')
        if contact.get('type') == representation
    )

def update_data(conn, id_row, row, data):
    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                "UPDATE dblgis_grabber_firm SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s;",
                (AsIs(row), data, id_row)
            )

def get_data(conn):
    with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor) as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""
                       SELECT *
                       FROM dblgis_grabber_firm;
                       """)
        return cursor.fetchall()

def check_data(db_credentials):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(db_credentials)
    for data in get_data(conn):
        fill_data(conn, data)
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    timeit.timeit('check_data("dbname=gym user=gyms")',
                  number=1, globals={'check_data': check_data})
```

## Beyond readable code

Good production code is not only clear but also correctly documented to be maintainable. You should spend some time writing some [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to help any future reader understand what your code does. Comments in the code can also help understand how the code accomplishes its goals.

Comment: Very appreciate, but is it better to open and close `conn` every sql execute? I make globals just for rely once to open and once to close. Thanks.

Comment: @kAldown I openned `conn` only once at the beginning of `check_data` and closed it only once at its end. The context manager associated to a connection object only ensures auto-commit/rollback; it neither closes nor creates the connection. See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement